# How to bundle system level dependencies for npm module with module itself for electron application?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, dependencies, native

I am trying to use [ppt-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ppt-png) npm module. To use this module I need to install system level dependencies which this module is using. Here is what I am doing

```sh
# First install these dependecnies
sudo apt install libreoffice-dev imagemagick poppler-utils

# Now intall module
npm install ppt-png
```

I am using this module in [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) application. When I will generate build for my application `ppt-png` will get automatically get included in installer but not `libreoffice-dev`, `imagemagick` and `poppler-utils`. I dont want anyone to install these dependecies to use this application.

How can I bundle these dependencies in `ppt-png` module itself or in electron to make application usuable without extra step of installing system level dependencies?